# Does PayPal IPN require SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, paypal, wordpress, paypal-ipn

I'm using a plugin called PayPal IPN for wordpress. The plugin generates an IPN URL, however, when I try and enter this IPN in to PayPal I get the following error message:

"We're sorry. That URL won't work. Please enter an “https” URL."

This was the plugin generated URL:

http://www.aeroex.co.uk/?AngellEYE_Paypal_Ipn_For_Wordpress&action=ipn_handler

I have entered other URLs before and have never seen this message, although the IPNs weren't sent properly. Does this mean that I have to get an SSL certificate for IPNs to be sent through? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears PayPal is now enforcing IPN URL's to be https. Meaning any eCommerce solution must force its users to install SSL/TLS certificates on their sites in order to utilize IPN's. I don't know what genius at PayPal came up with this one...PayPal is just the worst!

Here's the ONLY documentation that hints at this, and even then that's a stretch (nor is it September yet): https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1916&expand=true&locale=en_US

Current workarounds I can think of (please correct me if I'm wrong):

- Use Zapier endpoints (which are HTTPS) to capture IPN's and forward them on to your http endpoint
- Install SSL/TLS certificate on your site
- Setup your own form of Zapier on something like Heroku

Comment: @absikandar's solution also works for the time being. I have verified this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Remove HTTP from your IPN url and then try.

It worked for me on two sites.

For example instead of entering `http://www.ipnurl.com`, enter only `www.ipnurl.com`

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you user Paypal Standard, which send the user to paypals page, then no SSL is needed, however if you user Paypal Pro, which allows your users to pay in your website, then you should have an SSL.

Comment: I'm using PayPal standard with a HTML payment button which sends the user to the PayPal site, yet they are still asking for a https URL for my IPN URL so I guess the only option is an SSL certificate. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: It's weird, the paypal page your are sending to them is SSL, because I can user Paypal Standard without SSL at my server.